# Capture playback on play-only sound card with ALSA

Tags: linux, audio, audio-recording, alsa

My hw:1,0 is a playback-only external USB card. The recording application cannot capture the samples being sent to hw:1,0 if it tries opening hw:1,0 for capture. The alsamixer doesn't give any "[Capture]" options for hw:1,0 - just one volume control on "[Playback]" tab.

Is it possible to create some virtual "xxx" device that would accept a stream from playing application and send it out via 2 streams (copies) - first one to real "hw:1,0" (to my headphones) and the second one to another virtual device "zzz" that would provide capture ability, feeding the stream to applications that could open "zzz" for capturing?

**update**

I added ALSA Loopback device in kernel, now i have loopback device. Then i found working .asoundrc (see below), but when i capture screen + sound using ffmpeg, the sound goes WAY before than video, some great sync problem. So with this .asoundrc (below) i can use hw:0,0 (loopback device, hw:0,0 - play, hw:0,1 - capture) to capture what i send to "default". Also i can hear these samples via my external USB hw:2,0.

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg  -f alsa -i hw:0,1  -f x11grab -s 854x480 -r 30 -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 -vb 4000k /tmp/screen_854x480.avi
```

.asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "mdev"
    route_policy "duplicate"

}

pcm.mdev {
    type multi

    slaves.a.pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0"
    slaves.a.channels 2
    slaves.b.pcm "dmixer"
    slaves.b.channels 2

    bindings.0.slave a
    bindings.0.channel 0
    bindings.1.slave a
    bindings.1.channel 1
    bindings.2.slave b
    bindings.2.channel 0
    bindings.3.slave b
    bindings.3.channel 1
}

pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
            pcm "hw:2,0"
            period_time 0
            period_size 1024
            buffer_size 4096
            rate 44100
            channels 2
            format S16_LE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create loopback devices that reroute playback data back to a capture device:
[Alsa Loopback Devices for Fun, but not yet profit...](http://blog.vrplumber.com/b/1ZM/)
[ALSA Loopback for Fun and Profit](http://blog.vrplumber.com/b/1ZO/)

It is also possible to create a virtual device that outputs to multiple devices with the [multi plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html#pcm_plugins_multi).

Try something like this:

```sh
pcm.xxx {
    type plug       # <-- no { here
    slave.pcm {
        type multi
        slaves {
            a { channels 2 pcm "hw:1,0" }  # the real device
            b { channels 2 pcm "hw:5,0" }  # the loopback driver
        }
        bindings {
            0 { slave a channel 0 }
            1 { slave a channel 1 }
            2 { slave b channel 0 }
            3 { slave b channel 1 }
        }
    }
    ttable [
        [ 1 0 1 0 ]   # left  -> a.left,  b.left
        [ 0 1 0 1 ]   # right -> a.right, b.right
    ]
}
```

Comment: ALSA lib conf.c:1686:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:4:9:Unexpected char
ALSA lib conf.c:3406:(config_file_open) /home/xx/.asoundrc may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it

Comment: Oops, there was a surplus brace after the `plug`.

Comment: Thank you! Now i am struggling with sync problems in ffmpeg :)

Comment: ALSA is hard :) It works, but very out-of-sync with video. Also it depends on order you start recording and playing application. You must begin with starting playing application, then start recording app. It doesn't work vise-versa.

Comment: URLs have changed: http://blog.vrplumber.com/b/2020/05/18/alsa-loopback-devices-for/ http://blog.vrplumber.com/b/2020/05/18/alsa-loopback-for-fun/